Drawing an arc on a rectangle
As usual, I feel stupid because it seems like there is an easy solution to my problem... I just don't find it...
I want to draw an arc on a colored rectangle and fill this arc with white, so that it seems part of the rectangle is missing.
Here's a MWE and my result :
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzDefPoints{2/0/A, 3/0/B, 1/0/C, 4/3/D, 3/3/E, 4/2/F}
        \filldraw[blue, fill = red!50,fill opacity = 0.4] (0,0) rectangle (4,3);
        \tkzDrawArc[very thick, color = blue, fill = white](A,B)(C)
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \end{document}


I can't seem to get rid of this thin blue line on the bottom. I managed by drawing a white circle filled with white and then by cliping but... it seems clumsy.
Is there a better way ?
Thanks a lot !

Zarko's solution is fine. tkz-euclide is mainly intended for Euclidean geometry. It is possible to obtain the result with tkz-euclide alone.
It is also possible within the code to use TikZ from points that have already been defined.
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/O, 2/0/A, 3/0/B, 1/0/C, 4/3/D, 3/3/E, 4/2/F}
    \tkzDefRectangle(O,D) \tkzGetPoints{X}{Y}
    \tkzFillPolygon[red!50,opacity=.3](O,X,D,Y)
    \tkzDrawArc[very thick, color = blue, fill = white](A,B)(C)
    \tkzDrawPolySeg[very thick, color = blue](C,O,Y,D,X,B)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



thank you! I don't know all those commands you used. I'll look into it.

I'm not familiar with tkz-euclide, but with pure tikz this is simple:
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\path[draw=blue, semithick, fill=orange!30]
    (-1,0) arc (180:00:1) -- ++ (1,0) |- ++ (-4,4) |- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \end{document}



Thank you ! I'm familiar with -- and -- ++ but not with |-. What does it mean ?
Another question, what's the difference between "path" that you're using and "filldraw" that I tried using ?

@Kawahiem. -|˙ or |-are orthogonal coordinates: first draw horizontal, than vertical and vice versa. For details see section 14.2.2 Horizonal and vertical lines, pp 14&,tikzpackage documentation).\pathis generic command for drawing. It become visible with option draw(command \drawis actually shortcut  for\path[draw]. For more details see tikz` package documentation, pp 38,

thank you, I'll look into this.

Purely for comparison, here is a version in Metapost the drawing language built into lualatex.
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

  z1 = (4cm, 3cm);

  path semicircle;
  semicircle = halfcircle scaled 1/2 x1 shifted (1/2 x1, 0);

  path shape;
  shape = origin -- (0, y1) -- z1 -- (x1, 0) -- semicircle -- cycle;

  fill shape withcolor 3/4[red, white];
  draw shape withpen pencircle scaled 1 withcolor blue;

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}

Compile this with lualatex to get a PDF that looks like this:

I find it a bit simpler to define the <path> variables first, then do the filling and drawing last.
